# Enviar email para vários destinatários

Tags: c#

Estou com uma classe para enviar email, que funciona perfeitamente para somente um destinatário, porém preciso enviar para várias pessoas, fiz um select que busca os emails q preciso e coloca o ";".
Porém quando tento enviar desta forma, me retorna o erro "Um caractere inválido foi encontrado no cabeçalho do email: ';'."
Tentei colocar "," retorna o mesmo erro.

Tentei fazer assim:

```html
 var listaEmail = emailDestinatario;
                var emails = listaEmail.Split(',');

                foreach (var endereco in emails)
                {
                    email.To.Add(endereco);
                }
```

Ele não retorna erro, mas também não envia os emails.
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484503/sending-email-to-multiple-recipients-with-mailmessage

Comment: Qual o valor de: `listaEmail`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

listaemail esta recebendo todos os email que você deseja enviar separando com ",". se estiver

Tenta fazer assim:

```
                string[] emails = listaEmail.Split(',');

                foreach (var endereco in emails)
                {
                    email.To.Add(endereco);
                }
```